# Align text on each side of HTML 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I'm trying to align text on each side of a canvas element. This seems difficult to do via CSS.

https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/114#issuecomment-18564527

Am I missing something obvious? I think it may be easier to position the text as part of the drawing logic instead of dealing with CSS.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">top text</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">left text</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"><canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="250"></canvas></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">right text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">bottom text</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bootstraponline/HSh7m/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn each of the divs into inline blocks.

```css
.row:nth-child(2) div {display:inline-block; line-height:250px;
   vertical-align:middle; margin:.25em; padding:0; height:auto; width:auto}

#canvas {display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle; margin:0; border:0;
   padding:0;}
```

Note: the above is the answer to your question, but to make the result look more like the reference image, I had to add some decorative CSS as well...

```css
.container-fluid {float:left}

.row {text-align:center; width:auto; height:auto}

hr {clear:both}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HSh7m/4/).

Another note: the width:auto and height:auto etc seem to be necessary to counteract stuff in the the bootstrap stylesheet.